# Multiple SQL query fails if second where condition is empty

Tags: mysql

I have a situation where if the **flagged.reportcount** doesn't have any data, then the first part of the query doesn't return a result either. Sometimes reportcount will be empty, but I still need to retrieve the **user.reveal** data each time regardless.

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT users.reveal, flagged.reportcount FROM users, 
flagged WHERE users.id = '$userid' AND flagged.sidid='$sidid'");
$result= $sql->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: Change your query to an explicit left outer join.

Comment: I've tried both recommendations with no luck, is there a code example you might be able to add?

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.reveal, flagged.reportcount FROM (users, flagged) WHERE users.id = '$userid' AND flagged.sidid='$sidid'
```